# F# Code Quotations and generic functions

Tags: generics, f#

If you try to enclose a generic function between the *<@@* and *@@>* symbols, say

```
<@@ let f x = x in f 1 @@>
```

you get the following compilation error:

> Inner generic functions are not permitted in quoted expressions. Consider adding some type constraints until this function is no longer generic.

Is this an implementation limitation (a missing feature not implemented yet) or a conceptual problem (or maybe both)?

EDIT: just for clarification, the same error occurs even with typed quotations using symbols *<@* and *@>*.

EDIT 2: You can, however, annotate a generic function with the `ReflectedDefinitionAttribute` whose AST should be available through reflection.

Comment: does <@ let f x = x in f 1 @> work? -->    <@...@> Delimits a typed code quotation.

Comment: Nope, you'll get the same error.

Comment: is this only a example? If not the error says it all - you may not use inner functions to gene<rate quotations - that is a limitation with the quotations. In your special case you can just say `<@@ let f (x : int) = x in f 1 @@>`

Comment: @Carsten König. I'm aware of that. Thanks. I'm, however, curious to know if the problem lies in how quotations were implemented (i.e Microsoft didn't implement quotations for generic functions) or it is conceptually impossible to do that. So the _limitation_ concerns the quotations implementation or the concept of quotations?

Comment: @MSX I'm not sure but I doubt that it's impossible - I would guess that it just was not included into the Expression types

Comment: @Carsten König Personally, I agree with you. I had the opportunity to ask Don Syme about it at an F# conference, however, he didn't have much time to explain it and just said "That makes the things a lot more complicated." But I didn't understand if "a lot more complicated" concerns just the implementation. In my opinion, yes.

Comment: if you met Don at some conference then I am surely not qualified to answer *you* any questions at all ;) - My guess would have been that it uses `Expressing<Func<...>>` for inner functions and this does not work with generic parameters of course

Comment: the only place where this ever concerned me was in Websharper - and there it is usual no problem at all to either extract the inner function or give it concrete types.

Comment: @Carsten König Exchanging a few words with Don Syme during a coffee break at an F# conference doesn't make me an F# expert :) However, your comment reminded me that F# is open source so maybe I can check the code and see myself how quotations are implemented. Thanks!

Comment: @MSX of course this does not make you an expert - but usually you only find *good* people at those conferences (I never attendet a international one - nobody would pay my tickets and it would be quite to much for me) - and if you are confident enough to talk to the *big guys* I automatically assume you know your stuff - PS: good luck, maybe you can post your findings here. I know the github repo but this does not include the compiler stuff does it?

Comment: @Carsten König The conference was free and close to where I live. Plus, Don was chatting with everybody, even with me :) He's a very nice and humble person. Having clarified this, maybe we should stop chatting in comments before SO gets angry with us :)

Comment: @MSX hey no offense - I'm sure you are still a very competent person ;)

Comment: @CarstenKönig both [github](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp) and [codeplex](http://visualfsharp.codeplex.com/) should contain compiler stuff, but I will check and let you know if I find out something. For example, I already found [quotations implementation](http://visualfsharp.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/quotations.fs).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generic definitions would require lots of changes to the API.  For instance, the `Quotation.Var` type has three fields: a name, a type (represented by a `System.Type` value), and a mutability flag.  But if you have generic definitions, then you need to extend the variable's `Type` property to allow type *parameters*, not just concrete .NET types.  But representing these is a bit tricky - how do you make sure equality works properly (e.g. in `let z = let x (a:'a) = a in let y (a:'a) = a in x, y` the two `'a`s are independent and shouldn't be treated as equal, and the inferred signature is `z: ('a->'a)*('b->'b)`!

And it gets worse.  If the generic type is internal to the definition (as in your example), then at least the overall type of the expression can still be represented in the existing F# type system (e.g. as a `Quotation.Expr<int>`).  But if the type variable can "escape", then we've got some thorny issues.  For example, what is the type of `<@ fun x -> x @>`?  We'd like it to be something like a `Quotations.Expr<forall 'a.'a>`, but of course that's not a valid type in F# today.

That isn't to say that it would be *impossible* to solve these problems, but it would require a lot of design, implementation, and testing effort, as well as non-trivial changes to the type system.